# Creating a summary sheet from multiple workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a task at hand. I want to create a summary sheet by extracting data from multiple workbooks in a folder. These files are same in formatting. What i need to do is extract data from each workbook from the 5th worksheet. The cells are G4, H4, G8, H8, G10, H10, G17, H17. I found a code at [microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc837974%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

The code works fine when i provide only one cell like G4 or G4 and H4. The moment I provide the sourcerange as

`.Range ("G4", "H4", "G8", "H8", "G10", "H10", "G17", "H17")`

the code misbehaves. I get multiple rows for a single entry etc etc. I am not able to understand how to provide this sourcerange so that I get G4, H4, G8, H8, G10, H10, G17, H17 all in one single row inn the sourcerange variable. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub myLoop()
    Dim r As Range, cel As Range
    Set r = Sheet1.Range("G4,H4,G8,H8,G10,H10,G17,H17")
    For Each cel In r
        Debug.Print cel.Value
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried doing it. It wont work. If i give the input as .Range("G4", "H4") then i can extract the G4 anf H4 values. But if I give the input as .Range("G4", "H4", "G8", "H8") then I do not get any values. It seems like if the inputs comprises of values in one row (in this case the 4th row) then the code works. If I provide some non contiguous range then the code fails. I am not able to understand.

Comment: How are you extracting the the G4 and H4 values?

Comment: I've expanded on my original answer, have a look at it now.  It does work.